# In ASP.NET (C#), what is the proper way to render and reference collection-based forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, inline, code-behind, html-rendering

I imagine this question has been asked before (hasn't every question?), but I am struggling with the language necessary to find my way to a solution, so here are some specifics:

I have a web form for updating a single location, e.g. street address, city, state, etc., which is dealt with by having a static location-update form with various asp:TextBoxes which are referenced in the code-behind using their intellisensed controls, e.g. StreetAddressTextBox.Text.

I would like to update this form to work for multiple locations. In the past when I worked with PHP, this meant writing a lot of inline code wherein I wrapped the form-contents in a for-loop over the collection I was rendering, and then referenced each item with some `ID="StreetAddressTextBox_<%=locationId%>"`-like schema.

I'm currently in the process of doing it this way in ASP.NET, but inline feels dirty, especially because I have to kick a lot of code-behind paradigms I've established on other pages where the form-content wasn't scaling based on a collection. My gut tells me there should be some way to template out a location and do everything in the code-behind, but I've yet to stumble upon and example that shows me this in practice.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is this what youre looking for? www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081402-1.aspx

Comment: DataBinding and GenericDataSourceControl (totally awesome!) are your friend. UserControls can nicely create "new scopes", as it were, as they introduce a new NamingContainer.

Comment: @bUKaneer It's closer. I'm not sure how form controls are placed within a form, and how things like divs can be generated to contain them. This is sounding a lot like a job for javascript, once we start talking about specific control generation. I think there should be an HTML template I generate with injection points that can be reused across multiple locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming I understand you correctly it sounds like you should be using a UserControl.

Basically create a UserControl.ascx file (and VS will generate the UserControl.designer.cs and code-behind classes for you). Then put your input fields in there with no special attributes, like so:

(Note that I prefer HtmlControls to WebControls, they give cleaner markup and don't muddy things. I suggest you give them a try):

```
<%@ Control blargh %>
<label for="<%= Street.ClientID %>">Street address</label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="Street" /> <br />

<label for="<%= City.ClientID %>">Town / City</label>
<input type="text" runat="server" id="City" /> <br />

<!-- etc -->
```

Note how I'm not messing with the `id=""` attribute of the input controls. Now just register it in your web.config:

```
<add tagPrefix="foo" tagName="Address" src="~/Controls/Address.ascx" />
```

Then in each page that needs an address form (assuming your UserControl is called AddressControl)

```
<%@ Page blargh %>
<p>Enter your address details below:</p>
<foo:Address runat="server" id="Address" />
```

Then in your page's code-behind you can just do this:

```
 public override void OnLoad(Object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if( Page.IsPostBack ) {
          Validate();
          if( Page.IsValid ) {
              // get values from a POST
              String street = this.Address.Street.Value;
              String city   = this.Address.City.Value;
              // and so on
          }
      } else {
          // set values if you're retrieving data from a DB or something
          this.Address.Street.Value = "123 Fake Street";
          this.Address.City.Value = "Frying Pan City";
      }
 }
```

Note how I used the "<%= Street.ClientID %>"-thing. ASP.NET will automatically generate the control names and IDs based on the control's parent name (and so on, recursively). So the actual HTML input will be rendered like this:

```
<label for="Address.Street">Street address</label>
<input type="text" name="Address_Street" id="Address.Street" />
```

Note this design and practice only applies to WebForms. ASP.NET MVC is completely different again.

Comment: I prefer WebControls and "non-control" markup .. but I second the idea of using UserControls to separate components. I would *not* use `OnLoad` like this, however. Delay the validation and access **until** the event consuming the data. Doing things - various things, which requires a book just to itself - in `OnLoad` ultimately breaks the intricate page lifecycle and data-binding in ASP.NET.

Comment: Hrm, I feel as if may have miscommunicated. Imagine I hit a database or web service to serialize multiple locations for a user, e.g. new List<Location>(). I now want to generate an HTML form which contains fields for all of the properties of each location, e.g. a street address field for each location. Then I want the user to be able to submit that form, and in the code-behind I want to process it, updating the changes made to their locations.

Comment: Can I somehow generate `<foo:Address runat="server" id="Address" />` *and* `<foo:Address runat="server" id="Address2" />` *and* `<foo:Address runat="server" id="Address3" />` as I iterate a collection of locations in the code-behind? And then do some sort of FindControlLike("Address") or something, iterating and populating fields until it returns null?

Comment: Yes. Use `LoadControl("Address.ascx")` to create a UserControl instance from code.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <add tagPrefix="foo" tagName="LocationsControl" src="~/Controls/LocationsControl.ascx" />
  <appSettings> ...` Error 24 Unrecognized configuration section add. Do you have any idea why I'm getting this error?

Comment: If you use the concept of Dynamic Controls (as per my previous link) along with UserControls (i.e. Dynamically load UserControls) you should be able to achieve what you need.

Comment: @M.Herold it goes in the controls element in web.config. Google for "custom user control registration asp.net".

Comment: Thanks for all of your help. I ultimately decided to just run everything through to the front-end using Handlebars to template and Jquery for form-building, population and processing. Somehow more and less work at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an `<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" id="plcDynamicControls" />`.

In your code behind create a `private List<WebControl> dynamicControls`.

During `.Init()` return whatever logic is appropriate for your `locationID` requirements, and whatever your field requirements might be.

Say `locationID = 4` required Name, Address1, Address2 fields:

```cs
Page_Init(object Sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox(){
        ID = "txtName"    
    };
    plcDynamicControls.Controls.Add(txt); //Add to Form
    dynamicControls.Add(txt); //Add to reference list, to avoid having to do .FindControl()

    TextBox add1 = new TextBox(){
        ID = "txtAddress1"    
    };
    plcDynamicControls.Controls.Add(add1); 
    dynamicControls.Add(add1); 

    TextBox add2 = new TextBox(){
        ID = "txtAddress2"    
    };
    plcDynamicControls.Controls.Add(add2);
    dynamicControls.Add(add2); 
}
```

Build a nice loop to add controls like that to your placeholder.

In your `.Click()` event from your submit button you can iterate through the `List<WebControl> dynamicControls` collection and process the response.

Comment: The only issue with this is that I have structural elements which are used in the styling of the site. To write out a control element I'd also have to be able to wrap it in a div with a certain class.